# nginx mysterious error despite right configuration

Tags: nginx, php

I've installed nginx with php5-fpm and mysql and here is my configurations

```
 root /var/www;
index index.html index.htm index.php

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
```

It started successfully and was downloading files instead of excuting .
I know its a problem with php-fpm engine.

But now the server stopped and respond with problem loading page instead of welcome to nginx that comes the first time
And at terminal I see

```
  "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, 
       nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_pass" directive is not allowed here in/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default~:68
```

SO please help to fix that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor that you used to edit `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` left a temporary file `default~` (note this `~` suffix) in your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory. You should delete it.

Comment: removed the default~ and restarted the server but still give no reponse but if reloded it says welcometo nginx (if typed localhost/mysite)
else it gives no answer to(localhost/test.php)

Comment: At least it runs now. The next step should be to fix your configuration.

Comment: yes no returned to (welcome to nginx ) and downloads the files instead of running it.Drupal website gives (500 internal server error)

Comment: With such a small configuration snippet that you have showed it's unable to say where the problem is.

Comment: And you should check your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory for another temporary files    
`ls -a /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*~` that can be there.